What is inscribed in the One Ring in Khraniteli?
It looks as if the producers of Хранители, the (extremely loose) unauthorized  1991 Leningrad Television  adaptation of The Lord of the Rings, used a random gold ring to represent the Ring.
At about 25 minutes in, at the end of the scene where Gandalf is telling Frodo the story of the Ring, he says to  Frodo "Look! There is an inscription in the Ring!"



There is then a sequence with the Ring spinning on a surface, blurry most of the time, but it comes into focus for a few seconds, revealing letters inscribed on the inside of the Ring.
Not the expected inscription in Tengwar modified for the Black Speech, but Latin letters in some unknown language:
...ZMADEEST WYX RUUP FA...

Can anyone puzzle out the full inscription, what language (if any) it is, and a translation?

"Designed in California. Assembled in China."

Interesting that Russian TV chose the Latin alphabet to represent the Black Speech.

I'm not great with Slavic languages, but my head wants to  translate "zmadist" as "змадист" meaning "serpent-like".  No clue on the rest, but I don't think it's Russian.

Engaging Yakov Smirnoff mode: "In Soviet Russia, ring wears you!"

@DoscoJones One could argue it was true even in Middle-earth.

@Mithoron In the Shire Hobbits love eating the mushroom, in Soviet Shire, the mushroom...

@Lexible Meh, dunno 'bout mushroom... In Shire Hobbits smoke pipeweed, in Soviet... ;p

@Mithoron There is literally a chapter titled "A Shortcut to Mushrooms" at the start of The Fellowship of the Ring. :)

Google Translate was able to identify this as Wolof for "ZMADEEST TO THE WYX RUPE."  But that might just be coincidence :)

I don't think it's any sort of language, only random letters. Seems to me like someone had the presence of mind to use a believable distribution of consonants and vowels so it wouldn't look like a substitution cipher and that's it.
I can say with certainty that it isn't any Slavic language. It really doesn't look like a Romanic language, either. Same for Baltic. I can't strictly exclude Germanic languages (something akin to Dutch, maybe) or Uralic languages (like Estonian), but I deem them unlikely ("wyx"? not letters commonly seen there). (Quite sure it isn't German, English or anything Scandinavian out of Germanic languages, or Hungarian.) Similar for Celtic (only more for "ruup" this time). For all I know, it might be something that doesn't so readily come to mind and that I'm completely unfamiliar with even the looks of, like Albanian or something Turkic, but I doubt it.
If I'm to quantify, I'm 100% positive it isn't Slavic, 98% sure it can't possibly be Romanic or Baltic, 90% sure that this isn't a combination of letters that would be found in any Germanic, Uralic or Celtic language (considering the more promising ones of each), and about 80-85% sure that it isn't Basque, Albanian, Turkish, Azerbaijani, Indonesian or Vietnamese (doesn't resemble any of those in the slightest, but I'm only comparing with a text sample, and can't vouch for related languages).
If this was supposed to be a real language, one remarkable thing about the inscription is lack of diacritics. Some languages using the Latin alphabet are sparing with it (like English), but in most, even such a short phrase without any diacritical marks is improbable unless you actively make an effort with the phrasing to avoid all umlauts, accents, hooks, cedillas, strikethroughs or whatnot.
I also tried feeding both complete words to Google Translate. It thinks that "wyx" is English (not that it can provide a translation) and "ruup" is a transliteration from Bengali.
There doesn't seem to be any more visible of that inscription than you made out (not at the timestamp, anyway - I'm not watching the whole thing to find out if there's another opportunity), either.

This seems like a complete guess. "I don't know" is a very poor substitute for actual evidence.
